# How to overwrite all symfony2 form types and add some property (in version 2.2)?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

I want all form types to have `width` property, and to use it like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('product_name', 'text', array('width' => "small"));
}

public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);
    if (array_key_exists(self::OPTION_WIDTH, $options)) {
        $view->vars["attr"]["class"] .= " class_1 class_2 "
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more generic solution is to create a new Form Type Extension and register it for all types.

The Symfony documentation describes very well how to create a new Form Type Extension:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html

But it fails to mention *how* to register that extension for *all* types.

The "trick" is to specify "field" **(or "form" from Symfony 2.3 and next)** as the extended type (as a result in getExtendedType() and as the alias in the service configuration)

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Form/Extension/SpecialWidthTypeExtension.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SpecialWidthTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * Returns the name of the type being extended.
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'field'; // extend all types
    }

    /**
     * Add the width option
     *
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setOptional(array('width'));
    }

    /**
     * Pass the extra parameters to the view
     *
     * @param FormView $view
     * @param FormInterface $form
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        if (array_key_exists('width', $options)) {
            // set an "width" variable that will be available when rendering this field
            $view->vars['width'] = $options['width'];
        }
    }
}
```

The service configuration:

```
services:
    acme_demo_bundle.special_width_type_extension:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Extension\SpecialWidthTypeExtension
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, alias: field }
```

In Twig you must check whether the new option was set or not:

```
{% if width is not null %}
    <div class='col-sm-{{ width }}'>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: FYI: for Symfony 2.3, you must extend "form" and use the alias of "form" in your service configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Add it as an attribute...

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('product_name', 'text', array(
        'attr' => array(
            'width' => "small",
        )
    );
}
```

Then it will be on your fields as `width="small"`.

Comment: But i want to use it in function buildView to set attr class and other things.